# Why does Heroku not accepting my Node.js version?

Tags: node.js, heroku

With the following package.json

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.6.14",
    "npm":  "1.1.4"
  },
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "connect-assets": "2.1.9",
    "ejs": "0.7.1",
    "everyauth": "0.2.32",
    "express": "2.5.9",
    "less-middleware": "0.1.4",
    "mocha": "1.0.1",
    "should": "0.6.1",
    "socket.io": "0.9.6",
    "underscore": "1.3.3"
  }
}
```

I get the following

```
WARNING: No version of Node.js specified in package.json, see:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-versions
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to do git commit? :p

Comment: That same `package.json` works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing node version to something like this

```
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.6.x",
    "npm":  "1.0.x"
  }
}
```

This will try to attach "major" version should still work fine.